# Running multiple versions of PostgreSQL on the same Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I have PostgreSQL 8.4 and 9.0 running on the same server (Ubuntu Lucid).

I installed them both via apt-get (8.4 with the default package sources, and 9.0 after adding the ppa from https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/postgresql).

When I run a command like "createdb" from the command line or start up the "psql" shell, PostgreSQL version 8.4 is used by default on my system.

So, how do I force these commands to use PostgreSQL 9.0 instead of 8.4?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/q/582499/95758

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming Ubuntu does the same thing as Debian, then your two PostGreSQL instances will be running on different ports.

You can easily check the config files to see which version is on which port:

```
$ grep -H '^port' /etc/postgresql/*/main/postgresql.conf
/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf:port = 5432
/etc/postgresql/8.3/main/postgresql.conf:port = 5433
```

Most of the PostGreSQL commands take the "-p ####" or "--port=####" option, so you can use that to select the version you want.

Answer (score 13):

Use `--cluster` option e.g. (assuming that both clusters are named as default main):

```
psql --cluster 8.4/main
psql --cluster 9.0/main
```

Generic schemas are:

```
--cluster version/name      # for local connections
--cluster version/host:port # for TCP/IP connections
```

To list all installed clusters (name, port, status, data directory etc.) use `pg_lsclusters` command.

Check `man pg_wrapper` for more information.

Comment: This is brilliant how come this is not in the psql doc?

Comment: @MarHoff: The `pg_wrapper` is Debian's extension. Essentially, it wraps `psql` (that is, `psql` is symbolic link to `pg_wrapper` script) command with several new options to facilitate handling of multiple clusters.

Comment: Thank you! I use `pg_ctlcluster 11 main restart` to restart specific psql

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dpkg -L <packagename>` to see what files a particular package owns.  Run it with the postgresql 9 package and see where the createdb command for that version was stored.

Most postgresql commands would work cross-version with appropriate selection of the database by port or path, but this of course does not apply to start scripts and creation commands.