# How to manage different versions of PostgreSQL servers on the same host?

Tags: postgresql

I have PostgreSQL 9.4 and 9.5 on the same host with Ubuntu 14.04. My problems are:

1. When I run `service postgresql start|stop`, both versions start/stop. But I want to control which one to do.
2. When I use `psql` to connect to PostgreSQL, it always connects to 9.4. But I want to control which server to do. I know I can connect by different port, 5432 for 9.4 and 5433 for 9.5. But I want to connect by peer auth, that is via Unix socket.

I managed to find these clues for above two questions separately but haven't resolved my problems:

1. I find a command `pg_ctlcluster` may do the work but I don't know how to specify correct parameters, say, cluster-name. How could I figure it out? Or you have some other way?
2. Unix socket can be configured by `unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql'`. But both versions have the same config dir, within which there're subdirs `9.4-main.pg_stat_tmp  9.4-main.pid  9.5-main.pg_stat_tmp  9.5-main.pid` for different versions. When I do `psql -h /var/run/postgresql`, it just connects to the old 9.4 version.

Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: I guess I put the question & answer in the wrong place. Maybe SuperUser is the place where it should go. Could any admin help to make a move?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/q/582499/95758, https://serverfault.com/q/250192/95758

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, after some more effort, I get the answers myself:

1. Ubuntu and Debian offer a `pg_ctlcluster` as well as a serial `pg_xxxcluster` commands to manage multiple versions/instances of PostgreSQL on the same host. To find out the version and cluster name, just do `pg_lscluster`, which outputs like

   `9.4 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log
   9.5 main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log`

   For example, to stop 9.4, you use `pg_ctlcluster stop 9.4 main`. BTW, to disable autostart 9.4, `edit /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/start.conf`
2. `psql` need a `--port, -p` option to know which instance to connect, even for peer auth by Unix Socket, since all versions have the same `unix_socket_directories`. For example, `psql -p 5433 dbname` can connect by Unix Socket to version 9.5 running with port 5433, while default `psql dbname` connects to default port 5432, which belongs to my old 9.4 version.

That's it!

Comment: psql doesn't need --port if you use --cluster or the PGCLUSTER env variable. See `man pg_wrapper`. Incidentally this will also automatically select the version of psql that corresponds to the target instance.

Comment: For a machine with postgres 10 as well as 9.6, the `pg_ctlcluster` command arguments had to be inverted: `pg_ctlcluster 9.6 main stop` (i.e., stop at end)

Comment: Your command `pg_lscluster` is missing the final 's': `pg_lsclusters`

Answer (score 2):

On Debian-based distributions like Ubuntu, `psql` (and a few other PostgreSQL commands) is a symlink to `pg_wrapper`, which offers the `--cluster` option. See `man pg_wrapper` for details.

For local connections, you can use

```
psql --cluster 9.4/main
psql --cluster 9.5/main
```

To see your versions, clusters and ports, use `pg_lsclusters`. Sample output:

```
# pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.6 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
11  main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/11/main  /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log
```

And to set the default, you can set your preferred version to use port 5432 in `/etc/postgresql/*/main/postgresql.conf`, and to some other port for the other version.

(This was also answered here: [Running multiple versions of PostgreSQL on the same Ubuntu server](https://serverfault.com/questions/250192/running-multiple-versions-of-postgresql-on-the-same-ubuntu-server) )