# If I have multiple versions of Postgres installed, how do I use a version specific tool?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

For development reasons I have both Postgres 12 and 14 installed on my local machine. However, often I also need to use the `pg_dump` utility to create backups.

`pg_dump 12` won't connect to a Postgres 14 database and viceversa.

If I simply run `pg_dump`, Ubuntu will use the one in `/bin` by default which is `pg_dump@12`.

If I want to run version 14 I have to manually type:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_dump
```

Is there any way I can quickly switch between them?

Something like:

```
pg_dump@14
```

Comment: Can you just create different clusters for each (if I'm using the correct term)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, this is my local machine I use for development.

Comment: When initiall configuring postgres, you didn't use `initdb` to create a new database cluster?

Comment: No I didn't, I just installed it and created a database

Comment: I don't have extensive experience with postgres or anything, but you should find there is a directory, something like `/var/postgresql/data/` that stores the database cluster. You shouldn't be using different versions for the same cluster, and their should be a way to use the command only with certain versions and clusters. This is not at all uncommon, but I don't know how to do it in Ubuntu.

Comment: Also see this question which has solutions based on running each on different ports, t https://serverfault.com/questions/250192/running-multiple-versions-of-postgresql-on-the-same-ubuntu-server and not to mention there is always `alias pg_dump14='/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_dump'` but it seems like this problem should have a better solution somewhere if not SF then one of the SE sites.

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1. Your "viceversa" not working actually is not true. pg_dump is able to connect to databases of an older version. So a pg_dump version 14 should work with a postgreSQL 12 database.
2. You can just alias the full path to each version of the pgdump in your ~/.bashrc file ex:

   `alias pg14 ='/usr/pgsql-14/bin/'`
3. Then you can use `pg14/pg_dump`.